# How do I write firebase rule for this data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I use firebase to collect user ratings of articles from my blog. This is what the data looks like in firebase.

[firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm2qv.png)

When an article is rated for the first time, the **url**, **NumOfRatings** and **averageUserRating** is sent to firebase.
When the same article is rated by another reader, only the **NumOfRatings** and **averageUserRating** are updated.
Also, the user doesn't need to be authenticated to rate an article.

Please i have no idea on how to write the firebase rule.

Comment: Please avoid image for text content. Add some code. and provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's not clear what rules you want to set? Are you struggling with how to deny a user from updating the url on the second and subsequent ratings?